# How to extract data from XML File

Tags: linux, python, xml, nagios

I am trying to move our Pre-existing PRTG setup to a Nagios setup. The problem is that we currently have over 20k monitors, and so i'm trying to export the sensor information out of the .dat file and into a readable file that can be moved into a number of other nagios files. The problem is, I'm still very new to scripting and aside from creating a script that can split up the file so that bash doesn't kill itself, all attempts have failed. I tried to use a script someone else had written, but i don't think it will work for what I need it to.

I am needing to extract the following information Everything between host***/host and name***/name

If someone could at least point me in the direction where I could figure out how to write something that would allow me to extract a range of text, that would work as well. :)

Example:

```
<host>
10.0.0.0
</host>
<name>
This is a Business
</name>
```

Keep in mind this config file I am using is a .dat file that is almost a gig in size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root version="15" oct="PRTG Network Monitor 17.2.31.1917 x64" 
saved="5/12/2017 4:36:26 PM" max="184692" guid="{3A6843F2-61BB-47EA-8EB2-
B2E62E24EF2F}" treeversion="0" created="2009-10-02-19-22-11" 
<statistics time="12-05-2017 16:09:19">
```

Comment: you did not show the input fragment

Comment: Yea, I tried to by it came out as bolded and..

Comment: Here is the information I need out of the file. https://github.com/keyxmakerx/APIDigital/blob/master/example.txt

Comment: show the fragment with root (parent) tag, xml should have it

Comment: I assume that's what you are referring to.

Comment: use xmlstarlet tool

Comment: Hm, at first glance it looks way over my head, but at least i have a place to start. Thanks for your help :) @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: Maybe this link will help: [Extract XML Value in bash script] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333755/extract-xml-value-in-bash-script), or take a look at _xml_grep_ from the xml-twig-tools package.

Answer (score 3):

Use an XML parser like [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//host' -v '//name' file.xml
```

This would extract the contents of any `<host>` or `<name>` node anywhere in the `file.xml` XML document.

XMLStarlet is likely available through your ordinary package manager. The executable is sometimes called `xmlstarlet` rather than just `xml`.

Comment: Got some errors when doing this,
  PRTG Configuration(Copy).dat:14514917.69: PCDATA invalid Char 
  value 24
                                  MERAKI-CLOUD-CONTROLLER-MIB/dev:  
  &#x0d;/d

                     And                          

  PRTG Configuration(Copy).dat:14794305.35: xmlSAX2Characters: 
  huge text node: out of memory

Comment: If it helps.. [link](https://github.com/keyxmakerx/APIDigital/issues/1)